# What does "PER PARTITION LIMIT" means in cql query in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, scylla

I have a scylla table as shown below:

```
cqlsh:sampleks> describe table test;

CREATE TABLE test (
    client_id int,
    when timestamp,
    process_ids list<int>,
    md text,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id, when) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (when DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '1', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 172800
    AND max_index_interval = 1024
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

And I see this is how we are querying it. It's been a long time I worked on cassandra so this `PER PARTITION LIMIT` is new thing to me (looks like recently added). Can someone explain what does this do with some example in a layman language? I couldn't find any good doc on that which explains easily.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE client_id IN ? PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PER PARTITION LIMIT` clause can be helpful in a "wide partition scenario." 
 It returns only the first two rows in the partition.

Take this query:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT client_id,when,md 
        FROM test PER PARTITION LIMIT 2 ;
```

Considering the PRIMARY KEY definition of `(client_id,when)`, that query will iterate over each `client_id`.  Cassandra will then return only the first two rows (clustered by `when`) from that partition, regardless of how many ocurences of `when` may be present.

In this case, I inserted 7 rows into your `test` table, using two different `client_id`s (2 partitions total).  Using a `PER PARTITION LIMIT` of 2, I get 4 rows returned (2 `client_id` x `PER PARTITION LIMIT` 2) == 4 rows.

```
 client_id | when                            | md
-----------+---------------------------------+-----
         1 | 2020-05-06 12:00:00.000000+0000 | md1
         1 | 2020-05-05 22:00:00.000000+0000 | md1
         2 | 2020-05-06 19:00:00.000000+0000 | md2
         2 | 2020-05-06 01:00:00.000000+0000 | md2

(4 rows)
```

Comment: Yes, PER PARTITION LIMIT was just added in Scylla Open Source 3.1. You can even mix regular LIMIT with PER PARTITION LIMIT in the same statement. 

More here: https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/dml/#limiting-results

For Scylla, this was issue #2202 (https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/2202) that mapped to CASSANDRA-7017 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7017)

Comment: @Aaron I have another question on Cassandra schema design [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765467/optimize-in-clause-queries-cassandra). I wanted to see if you have any thoughts on my question?

Comment: For those using spark, `.perPartitionLimit()` is a viable command for RDDs to select 1 unique row in a partition.